# How to create entity translations using JSON:API or REST API?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I working on a headless localized site in which entities need to be synced regularly from an external source.

During the sync process, I need to create new entities and their associated translations.

I found out that [JSON:API doesn't support this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/translations). Are there any workarounds to achieve this in JSON:API?

Is it something that can be achieved with the REST API? If so could you point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal's implementations of JSON:API and REST do not support creation of translated entities at this time as far as I know.

**Create Entity Translations**

You could try hacking a custom [JSON-RPC route](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonrpc) or [JSON:API Resource](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources), but these are not really intended for entity creation and you would have to do a lot of coding.

If possible, I would use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to sync the entities and their translations.  You will need to expose the content to sync in a format that Feeds supports:

- CSV
- XML
- OPML
- RSS/Atom
- HTML/JSON

[There isn't a lot of documentation on multilingual Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3256925) but it does work.

**Create UI Translations**

This wasn't in your question but just as a note.  You can't create UI translations via JSON:API now, either.  One fix is to export your translations as a PO file and import the file with drush:

```
drush locale:import my_two_letter_language_code my_path/ja.po --type=customized --override=customized
```